# BigQuery DataSet and Project Id from arguments

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to be able to inject data set and project ID for a BigQuery query. For example:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1)
FROM @ProjectId.@DataSet.`StackOverflowPosts`
WHERE occurredAt > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: Could you provide more details about your use case? For now, is not possible to use parameters within the FROM statement https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

Comment: Thanks @ebeltran that clears it up. I'll stick with string formatting. The use case is different customers data is stored in different projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 5/20/2020, BigQuery [released](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#May_20_2020) dynamic SQL feature for you to achieve the goal.

> Dynamic SQL is now available as a beta release in all BigQuery regions. Dynamic SQL lets you generate and execute SQL statements dynamically at runtime. For more information, see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).

Your query can be written as

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(
  "SELECT COUNT(1)",
  "FROM ", @ProjectId, ".", @DataSet, ".`StackOverflowPosts`"
  "WHERE occurredAt > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'"
```

Comment: It's incredible how this powerful tool fails in the simplest things. Good trick Yun, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is [stated in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries). You cannot use parameters for structural components of the query:

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column
>   names, table names, or other parts of the query.