# How can I use the @@dataset_project_id system variable within a stored procedure?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have `sandbox` datasets in both project `project-1` and `project-2`. BigQuery allows me to set and use the value of the @@dataset_project_id [system variable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/system-variables) in a multi-statement query to specify which dataset to use for subsequent statements. But it appears to ignore it if the multi-statement query is contained within a stored procedure.

Using table creation as an example, if I run this in `project-1`, the table will correctly be created in `project-2.sandbox`:

```
  BEGIN
    SET @@dataset_project_id = 'project-2';
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sandbox.my_test_table (id STRING);
  END;
```

However, the system variable is ignored when running within a stored procedure. This will incorrectly create the table in `project-1.sandbox`:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project1.sandbox.sp_test`() 
  BEGIN
    SET @@dataset_project_id = 'project-2';
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sandbox.my_test_table (id STRING);
  END;
  call `project1.sandbox.sp_test`();
```

BQ acts the same way if I'm selecting instead of creating. It will query the wrong table, or tell me it doesn't exist if it's only available in the dataset specified in the @@dataset_project_id system variable but not in the project where the procedure is run.

I can tell if I query the value of @@dataset_project_id that it's properly being set within the stored procedure, it's just not being used. At least some other system variables, like @@time_zone, *are* set and used correctly within a stored procedure. How can I force BigQuery to use @@dataset_project_id in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67402555/19378826) applicable for your use case ? This uses execute immediate function of bigquery.

Ref:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've really been hoping to avoid changing all of our code to use dynamic sql. That would create all sorts of headaches for us. 

Just stylistically, it makes our code much easier to develop when I can just build a subquery on a different tab or working area without needing to add format and execution wrappers (if I build it as dynamic) or change it when adding to my main query (if I build it without dynamic project names).

That might still wind up being our workaround, but I'm still hoping to find a more direct approach.